# Group with overlapping index and apply function

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with datetime index:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

i = pd.date_range('1999-12-31 23:00', '2000-01-10', freq='2H')

x = pd.DataFrame(index=i, data = np.random.randint(0,10, (len(i),2)), columns=['a','b'])
```

How can I apply a function to groups that contain all hours in a day but also include the last hour of the previous day? E.g. if the function is `sum` the first group result should be this:

```
x['1999-12-31 23:00':'2000-01-01 23:00'].sum()
```

Second group:

```
x['2000-01-01 23:00':'2000-01-02 23:00'].sum()
```

etc

Comment: should the first group be from '1999-12-31 23:00':'2000-01-01 22:59' and not '2000-01-01 23:00' as the next group will be '2000-01-01 23:00':'2000-01-02 22:59'?

Comment: No, the second group should include the previous group's last 23 hour's entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
y = x.groupby(pd.Grouper(level=0, freq='D')).sum()
y[['a', 'b']] = (y.values + 
                 x.loc[x.index.hour == 23, ['a', 'b']].shift(fill_value=0).values)
```

---

Alternatively,

```
y = x.resample('D').sum()
y[['a', 'b']] = (y.values + 
                 x.loc[x.index.hour == 23, ['a', 'b']].shift(fill_value=0).values)
```

---

Comment: Yes, this does work indeed. Thanks. I was wondering whether a systematic solution is somewhere there in pandas, but probably not. And this seems good enough.

Comment: I could simplify a bit my first solution, @guyguyguy12345. Please, see my updated answer.

Comment: what if instead of the sum function, i want to convert to strings each element in the group and join them?

Comment: I guess the same solution will work, if you convert columns `a` and `b` to string before applying the proposed solutions, as `sum` concatenates strings.